# No Docker config.json in Amazon Linux EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecr

So in order to set up the `amazon-ecr-credential-helper` I need to add some lines to the `.docker/config.json` file in my EC2. When I try to run the script

```
  echo "{ \"credHelpers\": { \"acc_id.dkr.ecr.acc_region.amazonaws.com\": \"ecr-login\" } }" > ~/.docker/config.json
```

I get an error `-bash: /root/.docker/config.json: No such file or directory`

[image]

Docker is installed, I'm using root user. This is an Amazon Linux EC2. Can someone please tell me what is wrong here? Doesn't Docker already create the `.docker` folder? Or is this something I need to do?

Some context: I intend to run this script as part of the EC2 Userdata, but have been facing issues, so trying to debug within the container first.

Any hints in the right direction would be highly appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Doesn't Docker already create the .docker folder?"

No, Docker doesn't create a `.docker` folder in every user's home directory. You need to create that folder yourself.

Comment: Yep you are right, I went ahead and created it and it works as expected now. Thanks! I'll mark this as an answer once I'm allowed